# Bundle Products are being double discounted

Tags: bundle

I have several bundle products enabled at a discount. They're all set up and working fine.

We also have several discount codes, and I do not want the discount codes to be able to apply to the bundles, I told it to exclude anything in the "gift sets" category, where all the bundles are.

However, since the bundles have items from other categories (for example, the shirt and pants that make up the bundle are in the "women's pants" category) that the discount is valid for, the discount still goes through.

Basically it is applying the discount based on the child products in the bundles and not the fact that the bundle products themselves are in an excluded category.

HELP!